# angular-gettext does not pick the strings from .PO files

Tags: angularjs, django, angular-gettext, grunt-angular-gettext

I have installed everything according to documentation. Some of the things are working as per the documentation. Is there something like Django translation which automatically replaces the translation for specific language if you select those lang ?

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
{% load static %}
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'first.js'%}"></script>
<script src="{% static '/angular-gettext/dist/angular-gettext.js'%}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" >
    angular.module('first').run(function (gettextCatalog) {
    gettextCatalog.setCurrentLanguage('fr');
    gettextCatalog.debug = true;
    gettextCatalog.setStrings('fr', {
    "Hello!":"Bonjour !"});

});

</script>

</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="first">
    <translate>Hello!</translate> Sagar
    <h1 translate>Hello!</h1>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

PO file

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Project-Id-Version: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: \n"
"PO-Revision-Date: \n"
"Language-Team: \n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"X-Generator: Poedit 2.2.3\n"
"Last-Translator: \n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n > 1);\n"
"Language: fr\n"

#: ui/templates/admin/firsttranslate/index.html:24
#: ui/templates/admin/firsttranslate/index.html:26
msgid "Hello!"
msgstr "Halo !"
```

When I run my code It searches for Hello and Replaces with **Bonjour** But I want it to be replace automatically as Django does
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot mentioned the path of file in Gruntfile.js

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {
grunt.initConfig({
    nggettext_extract: {
        pot: {
            files: {
                'po/template.pot': ['ui/templates/admin/firsttranslate/*.html', 'js/first.js']
            }
        },
    },

    nggettext_compile: {
        all: {
            files: {
                'js/translations.js': ['fr/LC_MESSAGES/djangojs.po']
            }
        },
    },
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-angular-gettext');

grunt.registerTask('default', ['nggettext_extract', 'nggettext_compile']);
};
```